# Backtick-enclosed code doesn't display properly (example)

Tags: support, code-formatting

I absolutely cannot get the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848608/how-to-iterate-through-posts-of-custom-type-by-custom-taxonomy-type-advanced-or/3915990#3915990) answer to display properly. It's enclosed in backticks as I've been doing before without issue. I'm sure there's a known solution, but I can't seem to find it - any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you are doing it wrong.

Bactics cannot span mulitple lines, they are only meant to be used inline.

Indent code 4 spaces to format code.  See how I edited your question for an example.

---

When referencing a class like `String` or method like `equals(Object other)` use backticks.

But if giving a larger example:

```
// This code loops forever
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i--);
```

Indent by 4 spaces.  [(View source)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3c75a9ae-d5d4-448e-a609-ad25eafd532b/view-source)

Comment: That explains it. Awesome, thank you!